# Permission denied when restoring cache in CircleCi job

Tags: linux, bash, caching, circleci, circleci-2.0

Whenever my job run, they always take around 40s to download and install libreoffice. I'm gonna to store this into cache and restore cache to reuse it in next job.

```
      - restore_cache:
          key: cache-libre-6.3-b             # Restore libreoffice
      - run:
          name: install libreoffice 6.3
          command: |
            if [[ ! -d /opt/libreoffice6.3/ ]]; then
                # download & install the .deb
                mkdir -p /tmp/libreoffice
                l=download.tar.gz
                cd /tmp/libreoffice
                  wget -O $l https://download.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/stable/6.3.3/deb/x86_64/LibreOffice_6.3.3_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz
                  tar -xvf $l
                  d=`ls -td */ | head -n1`
                  cd $d/DEBS/
                  sudo dpkg -i *.deb
                cd -

                # install dependencies required when run :soffice binary  ref. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/13089
                sudo apt update
                sudo apt install -y libxinerama1 libgtk2.0-0 libxss-dev libgconf-2-4 libasound2

            fi
            # make :libreoffice softlink to libreoffice binary 6.3
            sudo ln -s /opt/libreoffice6.3/program/soffice /usr/bin/libreoffice
            sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/libreoffice6.3/
      - save_cache:
          key: cache-libre-6.3-b
          paths:
            # Save cache libreoffice
            - /opt/libreoffice6.3/
            - /home/circleci/cache-libre
```

When I rerun the job again, I can not restore cache. I got some permission denied below:

```
Found a cache from build 7593 at cache-libre-6.3-b
Size: 271 MB
Cached paths:
  * /opt/libreoffice6.3
  * /home/circleci/cache-libre

Downloading cache archive...
Validating cache...

Unarchiving cache...

Failed to unarchive cache

Error untarring cache: Error extracting tarball /tmp/cache785237819 : tar: opt/libreoffice6.3: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied tar: opt/libreoffice6.3: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied tar: opt/libreoffice6.3/CREDITS.fodt: Cannot open: No such file or directory tar: opt/libreoffice6.3: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied tar: opt/libreoffice6.3/LICENSE: Cannot open: No such file or directory tar: opt/libreoffice6.3: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied tar: opt/libreoffice6.3/LICENSE.html: Cannot open: No such file or directory tar: opt/libreoffice6.3: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied tar: opt/libreoffice6.3/NOTICE: Cannot open: No such file or directory tar: opt/libreoffice6.3: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied tar: opt/libreoffice6.3/help: Cannot mkdir: No such file or directory tar: opt/libreoffice6.3: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied tar: opt/libreoffice6.3/help/a11y-toggle.js: Cannot open: No such file or directory tar: opt/libreoffice6.3: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied tar: opt/libreoffice6.3/help/default.css: Cannot open: No such file or directory tar: opt/libreoffice6.3: Cannot mkdi: exit status 2
```

How can I solve this.

Comment: I seem to recall that appeared on their forum - have a search at discuss.circleci.com.

Answer (score 5):

This happened to me recently also. Given that I had many builds saving and restoring that cache using that key before it might have been intermittent and it's unlikely this was a direct cause; however, I would mention this just in case it happens to help people.

I had previously been playing with the `working_directory` command in attempt to use the `persist-to-workspace` and `attach_workspace` and think this could have caused the issue.

Sequence that might have caused error:

- Build A:

  1. set working directory `working_directory: ~/tmp`
  2. save cache with key X
- Build B:

  1. default working directory (did not use `working_directory` command)
  2. attempt to restore cache with same key X (but different working directory)
  3. `Error untarring cache: Error extracting tarball`

Solution that fixed it was simply changing the cache key. Such as from `v1` prefix to `v2`. This avoids attempting to restore cache that was made for working directory `tmp` to be attempted to be restored to different working directory. It now uses a fresh one.